# How to separate a plot into grids

Tags: plotting

I have made a plot using the built in function DensityPlot using the code below

```
DensityPlot[(E^-(x^2 + 
      y^2)^2)^2 + ((E^-(x^2 + y^2)^2) (x^2 + y^2) Cos[
      2 Pi])^2, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotTheme -> "Minimal", 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

Which generated this plot here
[image]

Now what I would like to is separate the plot into four grids (or n grids). The reason I would like to have these four grids, is that ultimately I would use the center point of each  grid (some x,y value) and substitute it in a formula to get an ellipse for that grid. Hopefully the why, helps a bit.

I have tried reading the documentation online, but I have not been able to find anything that can help me with this specific task.

I appreciate your help

Comment: "The reason I would like to have these four grids, is that ultimately I would use the center point of each grid (some x,y value) and substitute it in a formula to get an ellipse for that grid" this sounds like the question you _actually_ mean to ask. Are you sure you don't want to ask bout how to solve that one?

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** To get the centers of grid cells, you can simply work with the plot range:

```
means[n_] := MovingAverage[Subdivide[##, n] & @@ #, 2] &

centers[{nc_, nr_}, {xrange_, yrange_}] := Tuples[{means[nc]@xrange, means[nr]@yrange}]

{xrange, yrange} = {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}};

{nc, nr} = {2, 2};

centers[{nc, nr}, {xrange, yrange}]
```

> ```
> {{-(3/2), -(3/2)}, {-(3/2), 3/2}, {3/2, -(3/2)}, {3/2, 3/2}}
> ```

```
DensityPlot[(E^-(x^2 + y^2)^2)^2 + ((E^-(x^2 + y^2)^2) (x^2 + y^2) Cos[2 Pi])^2, 
 {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotTheme -> "Minimal", 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 Mesh -> {nc, nr} - 1, MeshStyle -> White,
 Epilog -> {White, PointSize[Medium], 
   Tooltip[Point @ #, #] & /@ centers[{nc, nr}, {xrange, yrange}]}]
```

[image]

Using `{nc, nr} = {4, 6};` we get

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
dp = DensityPlot[(E^-(x^2 + y^2)^2)^2 + ((E^-(x^2 + y^2)^2) (x^2 + y^2) Cos[2 Pi])^2, 
  {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotTheme -> "Minimal", 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

You can use `Show` with the option `PlotRange` to get the sections of `dp` you want:

```
ClearAll[divs, pieces]
divs[n_] := Partition[Subdivide[##, n] & @@ #, 2, 1] &

pieces[g_, {nc_, nr_}, {xrange_, yrange_}] := 
  Show[g, PlotRange -> #, AspectRatio -> Automatic] & /@ 
   Tuples[{divs[nc]@xrange, divs[nr]@yrange}];
```

***Examples:***

```
{xrange, yrange} = {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}};

{nc, nr} = {2, 2};

GraphicsGrid[Reverse @ Transpose @
   ArrayReshape[pieces[dp, {nc, nr}, {xrange, yrange}], {nc, nr}], 
 Spacings -> {0, 0}, Dividers -> All, FrameStyle -> White]
```

[image]

Use `{nc, nr} = {4, 6}` to get

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you say that you want four grids but do not specify the points, let me show you something that is perhaps a good starting point.

```
DensityPlot[(E^-(x^2 + y^2)^2)^2 + ((E^-(x^2 + y^2)^2) (x^2 + 
       y^2) Cos[2 Pi])^2, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Minimal", PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", GridLines -> Automatic, 
 Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick]]
```

which gives

[image]

You can look up `GridLines` in the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GridLines.html) to make it look better.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! By any chance do you know how I might be able to get the center point of each grid?

Comment: @PracticalFruit do you mean something like getting the coordinates for the central point of each single grid?

Comment: That is exactly, what I want to do

Comment: @PracticalFruit sorry but I have not managed to do it yet

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, you intend to partition your image.

```
pic="your image"
ImagePartition[pic, ImageDimensions[pic]/2]
```

[image]