# How to extract certain plot points from a plot with a grid?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have created a plot using the code below

```
DensityPlot[(E^-(x^2 + 
      y^2)^2)^2 + ((E^-(x^2 + y^2)^2) (x^2 + y^2) Cos[
      2 Pi])^2, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotTheme -> "Minimal", 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

To create

[image]

I have then separated my plot into n number (50 for this code below) of grids and found the center of each grid with the code (from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/246839/125)):

```
means[n_] := MovingAverage[Subdivide[##, n] & @@ #, 2] &

centers[{nc_, nr_}, {xrange_, yrange_}] := 
 Tuples[{means[nc]@xrange, means[nr]@yrange}]

{xrange, yrange} = {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}};

{nc, nr} = {50, 50};

centers[{nc, nr}, {xrange, yrange}]
```

If I plot my image using my grids and center points I get

[image]

My problem is that I would like to only get the center points of the grids that cover the circular shape.

**My attempt**

I have tried to initiate some kind of if loop that would be able to only pick out the corresponding co ordinates that are on the circular image from the second piece of the code (reposted below again). However I haven't been able to actually come up with a logical condition for this.

```
means[n_] := MovingAverage[Subdivide[##, n] & @@ #, 2] &

centers[{nc_, nr_}, {xrange_, yrange_}] := 
 Tuples[{means[nc]@xrange, means[nr]@yrange}]

{xrange, yrange} = {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}};

{nc, nr} = {50, 50};

centers[{nc, nr}, {xrange, yrange}]
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
dp = DensityPlot[(E^-(x^2 + y^2)^2)^2 + ((E^-(x^2 + y^2)^2) (x^2 + 
        y^2) Cos[2 Pi])^2, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  PlotTheme -> "Minimal", PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"];
```

Modify the function `centers` to select points that lie within a specified region:

```
ClearAll[centers2]
centers2[region_: Disk[{0, 0}, 1]][{nc_, nr_}, {xrange_, yrange_}] :=
 Select[RegionMember[region]]@centers[{nc, nr}, {xrange, yrange}]
```

***Examples:***

```
{xrange, yrange} = {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}};

{nc, nr} = {50, 50};


Show[dp, Graphics[{White, PointSize[Medium], Circle[], 
   Point @ centers2[][{nc, nr}, {xrange, yrange}]}]]
```

[image]

```
radius = 1.3; 

Show[dp, Graphics[{White, PointSize[Medium], Circle[{0, 0}, radius], 
   Point @ centers2[Disk[{0,0}, radius]][{nc, nr}, {xrange, yrange}]}]]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1]
rp = RandomReal[{-3, 3}, {15, 2}];
region = Polygon[rp[[Last@FindShortestTour@rp]]];

Show[dp, Graphics[{White, PointSize[Medium], FaceForm[], 
   EdgeForm[White], region, 
   Point @ centers2[region][{nc, nr}, {xrange, yrange}]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! But how will I now get the co ordinates of the points that are displayed?

Comment: @PracticalFruit, `centers2[Disk[{0,0}, radius]][{nc, nr}, {xrange, yrange}]` gives the coordinates.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi, for some reason, when I input the code you have above I get the plot with no white dots for some reason. Can you maybe think why?